# TFF : Modify the process that includes an initialization and iterated computation

Tags: tensorflow-federated

what can I write in this code :

```
def initialize_fn():
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The `state` object returned by `iterative_process.initialize()` is typically a Python container (`tuple`, `collections.OrderedDict`, etc) that contains numpy arrays. To see this, try `print(state)` after initialize.

Perhaps simply replacing the values with the those loaded from an external file after `initialze()` and before loop over `next()`:

```py
def load_my_weights(filename):
  # read from external file, create numpy arrays

iterative_process = IterativeProcess(initialize_fn, next_fn)
state = iterative_process.initialize()
state['model'] = load_my_weights(filename)  # assumes 'model' is a key in state.
for round in range(num_rounds):
  state = iterative_process.next(state)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I find this error: `NameError: name 'initialize_fn' is not defined`